# Why am I getting an invalid procedure or call error in my VBA code to link to SAP

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I'm trying to link my SAP to excel so that I can automate some report creating, but I seem to be unable.

I copied this code exactly

```
Sub SapExport()
If Not IsObject(SAPapplication) Then
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject(“SAPGUI”)
Set SAPapplication = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(SAPconnection) Then
Set SAPconnection = SAPapplication.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(SAPsession) Then
Set SAPsession = SAPconnection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
WScript.ConnectObject SAPsession, “on”
WScript.ConnectObject Application, “on”
End If
```

from [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/automatically-run-and-export-sap-transactions-out-of-excel-using-vba-9c63a28ff566) article into the code for my workbook and received an "invalid procedure or call" error when I tried to run. I did add an End Sub at the end because it refused to run without that. Any help is appreciated thanks. Once I get the connection functioning I figure it should be fairly straightforward as I'm decently familiar with writing simple scripts in VBA.

ETA the error is occurring inside the first if statement

Comment: Code is working for me. Where excatly do you get the error? Moreover the `Wscript` part in the code is totally useless in VBA. The recorder creates VBS code which is slighlty different from VBA.

Comment: @Storax the error was occurring on the line "Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject(“SAPGUI”)"
I was able to make it function by removing that line and changing the following to "Set SAPapplication = GetObject("SAPGUI").GetScriptingEngine", but worry that may make it not work as needed.

Comment: Your code contains invalid double quotes `GetObject(“SAPGUI”)`. Instead, use `GetObject("SAPGUI")`

Comment: @SandraRossi Good catch, that was the actual fix. Thank you, don't know how that happened